# HTML Broken Links

Tags: html

For some reason a couple of hours ago I was working on our website and all of a sudden the links stopped working. We were updating the back end too. These html files aren't even working locally on my computer. The links in the source are the correct ones. What could be wrong?

```
<div id="links">
                <ul class="leftNav">
                    <li class="leftLink"><a href="home.html" >Home</a></li>
                    <li class="leftLink"><a href="howitworks.html" >How It Works</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="rightNav">
                    <li class="rightLink"><a href="signup.html">Sign Up</a></li>
                    <li class="rightLink"><a href="http://bit.ly/SJNLot">Donate</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- end links -->
            <div id="social">
                <ul id="socialList">
                    <li><a id="twitter" href="http://bit.ly/SBBKAi" target="_blank">Twitter</a></li>
                    <li><a id="facebook" href="http://on.fb.me/SBBEZj" target="_blank">facebook</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- end social -->
```

Does it have to do with my doctype?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Comment: Which links aren't working? The local ones (`home.html`, etc.), or the remote ones (`http://bit.ly/SBBKAi`), or both?

Comment: what kind of "backend" did you update? Did you overwrite any config.php files or maybe even a htaccess?

Comment: We were updating python models for django.  Both local and remote links don't work.  We don't run php.

Comment: @Scott the link I mentioned in my comment maps to https://twitter.com/VTRelay, which is an active page.

Comment: Yes, but they don't work on my site either locally or remotely.  Here's the link: http://vtrelay.alwaysdata.net/teamList.html

Comment: Also when I talk about updating I mean, we reset the running processes currently running on the server.  But still, these html files don't work locally....

Comment: Found the problem.  This was in my javascript:
    event.preventDefault();